# Robocopy Job Summary Not Outputing on Screen of Log File

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am using robocopy 5.1.10.1027 on a Windows 7 pc in a batch file with the following syntax:

```
robocopy "%sourcedirectory%" "%sourcetarget%" /Z /log:log.txt
```

Robocopy copies the files fine but when it runs it does not output the job summary to the screen or the log file. The log file is created but the contents look like this:

```
1 0       1 0 0 0        3 0       3 0 0 0  130.8 k 0 130.8 k 0 0 0
```

Rather than this (according to the Microsoft user manual):

```
Total Copied Skipped Mismatch FAILED Extras
Dirs: 13 0 13 0 0 1
Files: 157 2 155 0 0 3
Bytes: 33.73 m 691.5 k 33.05 m 0 0 162
Times: 0:01:33 0:01:04 0:00:00 0:00:29
Speed: 10952 bps
Speed: 0.626 mb/min
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Martin

Comment: Have you tried using the `/TEE` switch?  From the RoboCopy help `/TEE :: output to console window, as well as the log file.`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the /TEE switch by itself and also in combination with /log: and the job summary still does not work.

-Edit, for use in a Batch file, this is tested as working.
`robocopy /mt:6 /tee /e %1 %2\ /log:C:\log.log`

Comment: How strange, I just tested using `robocopy /mt:6 /tee /e c:\src c:\dest\ /log:C:\log.log` and I got the stream of files being copied plus the summary at the end.

Comment: Updated my answer with code tested as working in a batch file.

Comment: My edited answer is waiting peer review (strange) but here's what works in a batch file `robocopy /mt:6 /tee /e %1 %2\ /log:C:\log.log`  -edit, forgot to add usage: `C:\>RoboFileCopy.cmd c:\SRC c:\dest`

Comment: I used your syntax to copy folders from c:\1 c:\2: `robocopy /mt:6 /tee /e c:\1 c:\2 /log:log.log` and the folders copied perfectly but the job summary did not display and the log file look like this `*.* /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /MT:6 /R:1000000 /W:30 c:\1\c:\1\Planning 1\22.docx33.rtfm m.contactc:\1\Planning 2\22.docx33.rtfm m.contactNew Microsoft Word Document.docxc:\1\Planning 3\22.docx33.rtfm m.contactxxxxx.contact                           4     3 1 0 0 0     11    11 0 0 0 0  3.4 k 3.4 k 0 0 0 0 `

Comment: That's wild, I've got the exact same RoboCopy version (both in SYSwow64 and System32) and if it matters, CMD runs as Administrator.

Comment: OMG I just ran the same batch file as Administrator and the job summary displays on the screen but the log file is not updated `robocopy /mt:6 /tee /e c:\1 c:\2 /log:log.txt`